# Html to pdf using jsPDF rtl support

Tags: typescript, converters, angular5, jspdf

I am trying to convert html to pdf with jsPDF using angular 5

Here is my code:

```
import * as jsPDF from "jspdf";
.
.
.
htmlToPdf(){
var doc=new jsPDF();
var specialElementHandlers = {
  '#content' : function(element,render) {return true;}
};

doc.fromHTML(document.getElementById('content'), 20,20,{
           'width':500,
      'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers,
});

doc.save('Reports.pdf');
}
```

I am trying to export the pdf with direction right to left without sucsses

When I try this command:

```
doc.viewerPreferences({Direction: 'R2L'});
```

I got an error: 'property does not exist on type "jsPdf" '

By the way in my html or css I tried to put direction attribute but it does not help. It still left to right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my component I used this function:

```
htmlToPdf(){
    const elementToPrint = document.getElementById('content');
    const pdf = new jsPDF();
    pdf.addHTML(elementToPrint, () => {
        pdf.save('report.pdf');
    });
```

In my html: I put div tag that warp all...  and with id="content"
i use the attribute dir="rtl"

```
<div id="content" dir="rtl">
.
.
.
</div>
```

Don't forget to add this script:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>
```

Comment: in 2021 the syntax is change . instead of pdf.addHtml it is just pdf.html. the function name was changed

Comment: you may right but I wrote it like almost 4 ya . people who still use angular 5 will have to use it I suppose.  But THX for noticing