# Generate pdf reports in Hebrew

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jspdf, pdfmake

I have tried all the react pdf generators to support Hebrew text. I successfully built the whole reporting system with pdfmake, but then I came to realize it doesn’t support Hebrew ( rtl ). I tried to change the fonts by looking on few solutions. Somebody please specify some package that can support Hebrew in a proper way. 
I don’t know how to add fonts to any of the packages.

Comment: Yes, I have been looking for the same answer.

Comment: maybe this will assist? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49154335/html-to-pdf-using-jspdf-rtl-support

Answer (score 3):

I am using [react-pdf](https://react-pdf.org/)

I had the same problem - Hebrew was gibberish.
Solved it by adding and using Rubik font.

In **react-pdf** it's pretty easy to add a font:

```
Font.register({
    family: 'Rubik',
    src: '/fonts/Rubik-Regular.ttf'
});
```

I also tried **pdfmake** but eventually chose **react-pdf** because it has better documentation and it had everything I needed.

Answer (score 1):

It helped me with Hebrew in react-pdf/renderer, but in PDF if hebrew has unicode symbols text is broken .
`Font.register({ family: 'Rubik', src: "http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/rubik/v3/4sMyW_teKWHB3K8Hm-Il6A.ttf" });`

It works in my app . But doesn't work if substitute in https://react-pdf.org/repl?example=page-wrap .Look for "Rubik" in this file (Ctrl + F and insert Rubik in search input): https://gist.github.com/karimnaaji/b6c9c9e819204113e9cabf290d580551, all fonts related to Rubik contain Hebrew characters .